# Return all rows if null value is passed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
select empno,name
from emp
where job = 'CLERK'
and empno = :empno
```

If I pass empno that is null I would like to display all the records that match the condition of job = 'CLERK'.  If empno is a specific number then it should filter for job and empno.

Anyway to do this in SQL without using PLSQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
and (empno = :empno or :empno is null)
```

Comment: Would it be better to reverse the order of these conditions so the null-check is evaluated first? Even if the SQL engine optimises it anyway, I would find it more readable the other way around...

Answer (score 3):

Something like this if pass parameter is null than replace it with the actual column value ...

```
select empno,name from emp where 
job = 'CLERK' 
and empno = NVL(:empno ,empno)
```

**How NVL work**

The syntax for the NVL function is:

```
NVL( string1, replace_with )

string1 is the string to test for a null value.

replace_with is the value returned if string1 is null.
```

Comment: I'd avoid doing this. Its purpose isn't very clear, since it relies on the logical equivalency "x = x", which is confusing. It also obfuscates the logic slightly, in that the functionality of `NVL` is unknown to a user that is unfamiliar with the function. @Andomar's answer is much clearer, since it relies only on descriptive logical operators.

Comment: have you tested this i think in oracle one null is not equal to another null so this might not work